# R : applying function on list of similar dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mean

```
df1 <- data.frame(Profit=c(7,2,8), CSR=c(1, 5, 9), row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
df2 <- data.frame(Profit=c(13,4,2), CSR=c(4, 2, 8), row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
df3 <- data.frame(Profit=c(6,2,5), CSR=c(3, 8, 20), row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
l<-list(df1, df2, df3)
l
dfmean<- data.frame(Profit=c(9,3,5), CSR=c(2, 6, 13), row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
dfmean
```

I want to call a function (here: mean) on all three (or more) data frames stored in a list, returning those data frames combined in one single data frame. In this case it should look like dfmean.

Comment: Do all data.frames have the same number of rows? And what you want is the mean of the elements in row 1, the mean of the elements in row 2 etc? Is it a one-off or are you looking for a more generic solution?

Answer (score 7):

You can add them all up with `Reduce("+", l)` and then divide that sum by the total number of data frames.

```
Reduce("+", l) / length(l)
#     Profit       CSR
# A 8.666667  2.666667
# B 2.666667  5.000000
# C 5.000000 12.333333
```

Comment: Super interesting use of those functional programming concepts (which honestly I didn't even know were implemented in base R). I fully expected to see someone come at this with a `dplyr` solution, and you might have held that gem in reserve to make them feel bad for doubting base R. ;)  Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

In a large dataset, I would suspect some missing values (`NA`).  In that case, you could use `mean` with `na.rm=TRUE` after converting to `array`

```
 apply(array(unlist(l), c(3,2,3)),c(1,2), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
 #        [,1]      [,2]
 #[1,] 8.666667  2.666667
 #[2,] 2.666667  5.000000
 #[3,] 5.000000 12.333333
```

Or use `rowMeans`

```
 apply(array(unlist(l), c(3, 2, 3)), 2, rowMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
 #      [,1]      [,2]
 #[1,] 8.666667  2.666667
 #[2,] 2.666667  5.000000
 #[3,] 5.000000 12.333333
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`, we `unnest` the `list` ('l'), create a grouping variable 'n', and use `summarise_each`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 unnest(l, gr) %>% 
         group_by(gr) %>%  
         group_by(n=row_number())  %>%
         summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), Profit:CSR)
 #  n   Profit       CSR
 #1 1 8.666667  2.666667
 #2 2 2.666667  5.000000
 #3 3 5.000000 12.333333
```

If there are no NAs, I think @josilber's solution is very compact and elegant.